# Trying to decide who rolls first in a simulation game

Tags: r, algorithm, web-services

The code is to be used to decide who shall be the first player in the game Wazabi (a popular game developed by Gigamic). So you understand the gist of what I'm trying to do, the following procedure decides who goes first:

1. Each player rolls a 4, six-sided dice consisting of three outcomes (three faces have 'W', two faces have 'C' and the remaining face has 'G', so there is a 3/6 probability you'd roll a W for example).
2. The player who rolls the most Ws wins.
3. In the event of more than one player rolling the highest number of Ws, the players who rolled the highest number re-roll the 4 dice, and then the player with the highest W becomes first (this may happen recursively).

I've designed the below code (albeit messily) in r to try and decide who this player should be, but after a few hours of attempts and a tired brain for company I'm hoping one of you will be able to help me out. Here's the output in R console from my code:

```
who_first <- function(){

  dummylist <- c()
  playersdummy <- 1:number_of_players

  first_rolling <- function(players_left=number_of_players){

    for(i in 1:players_left){
      # Random variable where 1, 2 & 3 represents Ws, Cs and Gs respectively.
      die_poss <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
      die_result <- sample(die_poss, 4, replace=T)
      dummy2 <- 0

      for(j in 1:4){
        if(die_result[j]==1){
          dummy2 <- dummy2 + 1
        }
      }

      dummy3 <- append(dummylist, dummy2, after=i)
      # dummylist stores the number of Ws rolled by each respective player, 
      # i.e. first element says how many Ws 1st player still left in rolled.
      dummylist <<- dummy3 
    }

    dummy4 <- 0
    for(k in 1:players_left){
      if(dummylist[k]==max(dummylist)){
        # dummy4 represents the number of players who rolled the highest number of Ws that roll.
        dummy4 <<- dummy4 + 1 
      }
    }
    return(dummy4)
  }

  while(dummy4 >= 1){
    if(dummy4==1){
      playersdummy <<- playersdummy[(which(dummylist==max(dummylist))==TRUE)]
      return(playersdummy)
    }

    else if(dummy4 > 1){
      dummy5 <- c()
      for(l in 1:length(playersdummy)){
        if(any((playersdummy[l]==which(dummylist==max(dummylist)))==TRUE)){
          dummy6 <- append(dummy5, playersdummy[l], after=l)
          dummy5 <<- dummy6
        }
      }

      # playersdummy becomes the vector containing which players are left in the game, i.e. 2 represents player 2.
      playersdummy <<- dummy5 
      dummylist <<- c()
      first_rolling(length(playersdummy))
    }
  }
}



 who_first()

 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 Warning message:
 In max(dummylist) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf*
```

number_of_players is globally defined in another function simply as the number of players in the game. **It is equal to 7 in this test.**

Clearly I should return a vector of length 1 with the player number for whichever player rolled the most Ws after however many rolls and rerolls. Also, as I'm quite new to R, I'm not exactly sure as to what the warning message is getting at, if someone could explain that'd be helpful.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Totally unclear. Please format.

Comment: okay, well after formatting i have found that this is not reproducible. It is hard to understand what you code is doing, more so as we do not have the data . inputs that you use in your function. I would advice stepping through your code one line at a time (ie not within a function) to see where the errors are.

Comment: My apologies, it's my first time posting & I'm not quite familiar with the functions of the site. The only exterior input I've used is stated below the function in the edit I've just made.

Comment: `max(c())` is probably it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that apparently follows your algorithm but is much simpler than your attempt.

The idea is simple: Since there's no difference between the C and G outcomes, you can just make them the same, valued 0. Make the W outcome 1, and sum the number of times it's been rolled. Then check if there's a winner, if not, keep only the highest ties and repeat.

It does seem that it would be much simpler to just roll the dice once and, in case of a tie, keep those and roll again. But maybe there's more to it.

```
who_first <- function(n) {
  players <- seq_len(n)
  found_winner <- FALSE
  die_poss <- c(rep(c(0, 1), each = 3))
  while (!found_winner) {
    cat("Rolling for players", paste(players, collapse = ", "), "\n")
    results <- replicate(length(players), sum(sample(die_poss, 4, replace=T)))
    cat("Players rolled", paste(results, collapse = ", "), "points\n")
    if (sum(max(results) == results) == 1) {
      found_winner <- TRUE
      winner <- players[which.max(results)]
      cat("Winner is player", winner, "\n")
    } else {
      players <- players[max(results) == results]
    }
  }
  invisible(winner)
}
```

Some runs:

```
> set.seed(10)
> who_first(7)
Rolling for players 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 
Players rolled 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2 points
Rolling for players 3, 6 
Players rolled 2, 2 points
Rolling for players 3, 6 
Players rolled 4, 1 points
Winner is player 3 
> who_first(7)
Rolling for players 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 
Players rolled 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1 points
Winner is player 6 
> who_first(7)
Rolling for players 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 
Players rolled 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2 points
Rolling for players 1, 6 
Players rolled 0, 3 points
Winner is player 6
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The simplicity is much appreciated also. May I ask the following two things however?     
1) function(i) sum(sample(die_poss, 4, replace=T)) is the FUN argument of supply, yet is this saying the function you are applying is 'sum(sample(die_poss, 4, replace=T))' and you've inserted function(i) to clarify this?
2) If max(results) %in% results is boolean and returns either TRUE or FALSE, then taking the sum of these would either be 1 or 0, not anything higher, so the winner would always be found on the first turn. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @MckenzieWilliamHowells 1. `function(i)` is required because of how the `sapply` is written, even though `i` isn't used. I changed it to `replicate` which is better suited in this case. 2. Yes, I shouldn't have used `%in%`, you're right. Replacing with `==` solves that though. There was also another error with the code though that I just fixed. I replaced the code with a verbose function to print the partial outcomes.

Comment: Again, thanks very much. You've made what seemed to be a very complicated code much simpler, and you've implored me to learn a few new functions in R that'll undoubtedly come in handy. Have a nice day!